# How can I persist $SHELLOPTS in sudo

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

When I sudo to root vi mode is turned off, so that I need to either run `set -o vi` or change root's profile to use vi mode. I don't want to change the profile as this will impact other engineers and I don't want to have to type set -o vi every time I sudo. I read man sudo and tried `sudo -i` and `sudo -sE`, but neither of these preserved `$SHELLOPTS` where vi mode is set.

I did find that setting `env_keep += SHELLOPTS` in /etc/sudoers fixed the issue, but this file is being maintained by a config mgmt system and I don't want to make such a global change just because I prefer vi as my command line editor. So, ultimately is there a way I can set this when sudoing that will not require making changes to shared and/or managed config files?

```
[user@host:~]$ echo $SHELLOPTS
braceexpand:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:vi
[user@host:~]$ sudo -i
[root@host:~]# echo $SHELLOPTS
braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor

[user@host:~]$ sudo -sE
[root@host:~]# echo $SHELLOPTS
braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor
```

Comment: I think `-E` and `env_keep` **are** how you do this. You can modify the root profile to check `SUDO_USER` if you want to limit it to just you though.

Comment: Actually Etan using env_keep in conjunction with the -E flag actually prevents the proper SHELLOPTS setting from being kept. I think this is due to the fact that SHELLOPTS is not set in the "env" as defined by the sudo logic. Did you know you can't actually set SHELLOPTS via an export command like you would with other environment variables? It will give an error that it is a readonly variable. 

`[user@host ~]$ sudo -sE
[root@host user]# echo $SHELLOPTS
braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor`

Comment: As you can see here using `sudo -s` actually allows the env_keep settings to work. I didn't make any other changes between these two commands.

`[user@host ~]$ sudo -s
[root@host user]# echo $SHELLOPTS
braceexpand:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:vi`

Comment: I think `-E` only works if the config says it should. And `env_keep` doesn't need `-E` (though I would think that both would work together just fine but maybe not). But my point was that you already found the correct options for this as far as I know. (Though it looks like you could try just setting it manually in the call `sudo -s "SHELLOPTS='$SHELLOPTS' /bin/bash"` or similar, possibly.)